# Adding Contact groups using swift in IOS

Tags: ios, swift, cncontactstore

Is it possible to programmatically add a group to Contacts in IOS using swift.

If so has anyone some sample code

Comment: Check : https://www.raywenderlich.com/97936/address-book-tutorial-swift-ios

Comment: That Ray Wenderlich article uses the old AddressBook framework, and is deprecated. This newer one deals with the Contacts API, but doesn't cover groups https://www.raywenderlich.com/2547730-contacts-framework-tutorial-for-ios

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Contacts | Apple Developer Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/contacts) for some basic examples.

You can also download an entire [example app](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/ManagingContacts/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40017031-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2) from the Developer site. It demonstrates many aspects of handling groups and contacts.

And, finally, here is some basic code for creating a group as of Swift 4:

```
func createCNGroup() {  
    let groupName = "My Group Name"
    let saveRequest = CNSaveRequest()

    let group = CNMutableGroup()
    group.name = groupName

    saveRequest.add(group, toContainerWithIdentifier: nil)

    do {
        try contactStore.execute(saveRequest)
    }
    catch {
        let err = error as! CNError
        print("Error saving group:\n\(err)")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  You can call `ABGroupCreate` which is documented here

https://developer.apple.com/reference/addressbook/1430086-abgroupcreate

Comment: `ABGroupCreate` is part of the older [`AddressBook` framework](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/addressbook#main). It is being deprecated and replaced with [`Contacts`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/contacts) and [`ContactsUI`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/contactsui) frameworks.